# Ubuntu 16.04 synaptics touch pad behaves erratically, not working

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

The synaptics touch pad on ACER Aspire VN7-592G laptop behaves erratically, or just does not work. I have the Nvidia drivers installed.

I have tried reducing the "Synaptics Touch" through xinput set-props command sensitivity as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

While using xinput to turn on palm detect works, the touchpad still detects multiple touches when only touching with one finger and often is completely unresponsive. Annoyingly, it seems to work flawlessly about 50% of the time.